# Autoit COM Error opening a PPT/PPTX

Tags: com, powerpoint, autoit

When i try top open the the PPT, instead of creating a new one (which works fine!), I am getting the following error

```
$objPPT = _PPT_PowerPointApp()
If @error Then 
    MsgBox(0,"","No PowerPoint available") 
    Exit
EndIf
$PresInterface = _PPT_CreatePresentation($objPPT) ;Get presentation 
interface$objPres = _PPT_PresentationOpen($PresInterface,"C:\Users\s.mailappan\Desktop\3G-Reports\MyAutoItPresentation.ppt") ;Add a new presentation
```

[image: COM Error while opening a PPT/PPTX]

Comment: the last two lines are probably messed up? there shouldn't be the "interface" directly before your variable `$objPres`...

Comment: Yep...I got that working! Thanks anyway!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To open an existing PPT, need to get rid of the following line from my original code.

```
$PresInterface = _PPT_CreatePresentation($objPPT) ;Get presentation
```

Which makes the following code to work.

```
$objPPT = _PPT_PowerPointApp()
If @error Then 
    MsgBox(0,"","No PowerPoint available") 
    Exit
EndIf

$objPres = _PPT_PresentationOpen($objPPT,"C:\Users\s.mailappan\Desktop\3G-Reports\MyAutoItPresentation.ppt") ;Add a new presentation
```